# How can I dump the schema of a SQL server database on Linux?

Tags: sql-server

UPDATE:
My goal is to get a set of SQL commands that can b executed and would recreate the database that I made including all the resources such as tables, indexes, trigger functions, privilege grants etc - same as what the MySQL and POstgres commands below do.  I'm working on an open source project and I want to be able to give a sql file to the end user so all they ned to do is run it to get their database correctly set up.

On MySQL:

```
mysqldump --no-data somedatabasename dump_schema_mysql.out
```

On Postgres:

```
pg_dump -s somedatabasename > dump_schema_postgres.out
```

I can't seem to find an equivalent for SQL server on Linux, though surely such a common task must be easily done?

I have the sqlcmd utility running ok:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sqlcmd -?
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Command Line Tool
Version 17.6.0001.1 Linux
Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

usage: sqlcmd            [-U login id]          [-P password]
  [-S server or Dsn if -D is provided]
  [-H hostname]          [-E trusted connection]
  [-N Encrypt Connection][-C Trust Server Certificate]
  [-d use database name] [-l login timeout]     [-t query timeout]
  [-h headers]           [-s colseparator]      [-w screen width]
  [-a packetsize]        [-e echo input]        [-I Enable Quoted Identifiers]
  [-c cmdend]
  [-q "cmdline query"]   [-Q "cmdline query" and exit]
  [-m errorlevel]        [-V severitylevel]     [-W remove trailing spaces]
  [-u unicode output]    [-r[0|1] msgs to stderr]
  [-i inputfile]         [-o outputfile]
  [-k[1|2] remove[replace] control characters]
  [-y variable length type display width]
  [-Y fixed length type display width]
  [-p[1] print statistics[colon format]]
  [-R use client regional setting]
  [-K application intent]
  [-M multisubnet failover]
  [-b On error batch abort]
  [-D Dsn flag, indicate -S is Dsn]
  [-X[1] disable commands, startup script, environment variables [and exit]]
  [-x disable variable substitution]
  [-g enable column encryption]
  [-G use Azure Active Directory for authentication]
  [-? show syntax summary]
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sqlcmd -?
```

Comment: There is no "dump the schema" equivalent in SQL Server. If you give us an idea of what you're expecting for output, though, we might be more able to help.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I've updated the question ..... essentially I want to be able to run a script that reproduces the structure of a database on another SQL server.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [mssql-scripter](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-scripter). It's cross-platform and created by Microsoft. It has a bunch of options to control how the scripting happens.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1. Use [`DBCC CLONEDATABASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-clonedatabase-transact-sql) to create an empty copy of the database on the same server
2. Use native backup/restore (or [`#Copy-DbaDatabase`](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Copy-DbaDatabase) from [dbatools](https://docs.dbatools.io)) to copy to a different server.

Some other (mostly more tedious) options:

- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21880974/61305), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54309156/61305), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12036458/61305), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2417880/61305), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38306290/61305), [here](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/copy-database-schemas-without-data-sql-server/)

[SQL Clone](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-clone/) sounds like a viable commercial offering, though I am not certain it handles a schema/structure only option.

Answer (score 1):

Your situation can be solved by using a GUI (namely, SSMS - SQL Server Management Studio) and connecting to your SQL Server instance on your Linux box.

You can then right-click on the database and select **Tasks** | **Generate Scripts...**:

[image: Database --> Tasks --> Generate Scripts...]

This will open up the **Generate Scripts** wizard, which will guide you through the process:

## Generate Scripts

#### Introduction

[image: Introduction]

#### Choose Objects

[image: Choose Objects]

#### Set Scripting Options

The following screen can be important, as it gives you access to the **Advanced** options via the same button.

[image: Set Scripting Options]

#### Advanced Scripting Options

Here you can select the Version of the SQL Server you will be scripting for (Script for Server Version) and if you want to script out either the Schema, the Schema & Data or just the Data only (Types of data to script):

[image: Advanced Scripting Options]

#### Summary

After you have selected all your options and clicked on **Next >** you will be presented with a summary.

[image: Summary]

#### Save Scripts

The last screen performs the scripting and saves the information according to your settings.

[image: Save Scripts]

#### Execute Script

The script can then be executed on any other target SQL Server instance, to create the database (depends on your settings) and the schemas and/or data.

We have successfully down-graded SQL Server 2019 databases to SQL Server 2017 using this approach. However, we weren't using any 2019 features in the 2019 database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sqlpackage utility on Linux to accomplish this.  The nice thing about sqlpackage is that it considers dependencies, constraints, various database settings when producting the deployment script.

There are also [a ton of options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-ver15#script-parameters-and-properties) available for customizing the script output in an automated way (so that you don't have to hand-edit anything in the generated script).

Doing this requires two steps (after [installing it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage-download?view=sql-server-2017#get-sqlpackage-net-core-for-linux)):

1. Create a dacpac file from the existing database (which is a model of the database schema)

```
sqlpackage /Action:"Extract" /SourceServerName:".\SQL2019,8677" /SourceDatabaseName:"StackOverflow2010" /SourceUser:"test-user" /SourcePassword:"SomePassword" /TargetFile:"./StackOverflow2010.dacpac"
```

Which outputs:

```
Connecting to database 'StackOverflow2010' on server '.\SQL2019,8677'.  
Extracting schema  
Extracting schema from database  
Resolving references in schema model  
Successfully extracted database and saved it to file '/home/jdarnell/sqlpackage/StackOverflow2010.dacpac'.  
Time elapsed 00:00:08.06
```

2. Create a deployment script from the dacpac.  Notice I've set the "CreateNewDatabase" flag to "true" since you mentioned this is for installation.

```
sqlpackage /Action:"Script" /SourceFile:"./StackOverflow2010.dacpac" /DeployScriptPath:"./deploy.sql" /TargetServerName:".\SQL2019,8677" /TargetDatabaseName:"StackOverflow2010" /TargetUser:"test-user" /TargetPassword:"SomePassword" /p:CreateNewDatabase=true
```

Which outputs:

```
Generating publish script for database 'StackOverflow2010' on server '.\SQL2019,8677'.
Initializing deployment (Start)
*** The object [test-user] already exists in database with a different definition and will not be altered.
Initializing deployment (Complete)
Analyzing deployment plan (Start)
Analyzing deployment plan (Complete)
Reporting and scripting deployment plan (Start)
Reporting and scripting deployment plan (Complete)
Successfully generated script to file /home/jdarnell/sqlpackage/deploy.sql.
Time elapsed 00:00:16.36
```